# How to use debug log in golang

Tags: go

I’ve application which should use log in state of debug. i.e. all the logs that I want to 
provide is like log.debug

I’ve read about it and find the following

```
https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus
https://github.com/uber-go/zap
```

My question is how should I “tell” to the program that now run at debug mode an then 
all the logs will be printed since this I believe should come from outside …
**example will be very helpful** since Im new to golfing .

Comment: Check codebases that are out there. In go, the common way to do that is to load configuration via environment variables (eg `LOG_LEVEL`, and use `os.Getenv` or a config package to load the value). That's why `logrus` for example allows you to set log levels via ints _or_ strings.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - Can you please provide example how to init and use it via logrus ?

Comment: Posted a minimal example. TBH: just read the _readme_ of the logrus repository, It contains [an example](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus#example) where the log level is actually being set.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, a really simple example of the approach I suggested in the comment:

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func init() {
    lvl, ok := os.LookupEnv("LOG_LEVEL")
    // LOG_LEVEL not set, let's default to debug
    if !ok {
        lvl = "debug"
    }
    // parse string, this is built-in feature of logrus
    ll, err := logrus.ParseLevel(lvl)
    if err != nil {
        ll = logrus.DebugLevel
    }
    // set global log level
    logrus.SetLevel(ll)
}

func main() {
    logrus.Debug("Will only be visible if the loglevel permits it")
}
```

The original comment:

> Check codebases that are out there. In go, the common way to do that is to load configuration via environment variables (eg LOG_LEVEL, and use os.Getenv or a config package to load the value). That's why logrus for example allows you to set log levels via ints or strings.

Please, please: before you ask a question, read the basic info about the packages you use. Even the github repo for logrus' main README contains an example setting the log level to a specific level:

https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus#example

Comment: Thanks 1+ I've tried your suggestion which is good idea but not working :( in both case the log is printed `if !ok` and `if ok` , why ?

Comment: in both case it get `5` for debug level

Comment: and btw, does it good practice to put it on `init` function ?

Comment: In this example, unless you set the log level to something other than debug (eg `info`), you'll always see debug log output. Check the implementation of the `ParseLevel` function to see what string values you can assign to `LOG_LEVEL`. Having this in the `main.init` func is acceptable, but in most cases you'll want to configure some other things, and you'll end up setting up the logger in the `main` func somewhere. It all depends. In this small example, this is a valid use-case of the `init` func though

Comment: logrus is not continuing its support. Its better to jump to zap for all new projects.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.  I think what the op (and I) was looking for is a mechanism or argument for modifying log level w/o add'l code.  Based on this and what else I have seen, it doesn't happen that way.

Comment: @rfportilla I can't speak for the OP, but this is a 5y old question, and the OP marked this answer as accepted. You can change the log level of an application at runtime though. I tend to use file-based config and `fsnotify` for things like that. Have a config file with log levels, if that file is updated, reload the config, and use callbacks to set the log level to the updated value.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am learning Golang also.  This question is still relevant and answers can be changed.  What I was looking for here is a way to set this without having to look at an env var.  For ex., golang run ... -set loglevel=debug;  That is how I read the question.  Apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: @rfportilla No need to apologise. All in all, though, using `go run` is not something that is recommended, especially not when you're running something that requires bootstrapping (which your example of `go run -set loglevel=debug` implies). I'd recommend you use `go build` and execute the binary, and have a look at `fsnotify` to use file-based config that can be reloaded at runtime

Answer (score 2):

If the only thing you need is check level before printing  you can create you own thin wrapper for standard logger.

This will help to better understand how they work. Feel free to ask any questions.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
)

type MyLog struct {
    PrintDebug bool
}

func (m *MyLog) Debug(args ...interface{}) {
    if m.PrintDebug {
        m.Print(args...)
    }
}

func (m *MyLog) Print(args ...interface{}) {
    log.Print(args...)
}

func main() {
    ml := MyLog{}
    ml.Debug("PrintDebig = false, so no oitput")
    ml.Print("this will be printed anyway")

    ml.PrintDebug = true
    ml.Debug("Hello, playground")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gKxQtC9NqX

Comment: Thanks, assume I want to influence from outside (my application should be deployed to the cloud) the program on the log i.e. flag/env to print debug.log or not , how should I do it ?

Comment: This is a poor implementation: it's not thread safe (no assignment is, unless you use the `atomic` package). You're not really implementing different _levels_. OP mentions `logrus`, which _does_ have differen log levels. Why wouldn't you simply use that instead? Lastly: the question was mainly focused on _how_ you switch to a different log level: hard-coding a boolean reassignment wouldn't be the way to go I don't think

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem that's a start point to understand better how to start. If you understand logics than bool can be switched to any else and analogue methods like `Debug`, `Warn` and `Critical` implemented. Usually you do not switch DebugLevels on fly, so bool var is really written only once. Original Logger is thread safe.  Logrus is nice, but it has some drawbacks - for example bad handling of line numbers, what standard logger can do well. Solution

Comment: Logrus' issues aside, the OP was mainly asking _how_ to set the loglevel, to which the answer would be: this is commonly done through environment variables. Your answer is a simplistic implementation using boolean flags. The OP already mentioned logrus, so I'd assume he's using that, and is mainly trying to find out how to turn debug logging on/off